# Tiled 2d World Map Size Issue

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Hey all, I am creating a 2D tile based XNA game. Basically the character can move any direction one tile at a time. I am using the Tiled map editor: http://www.mapeditor.org/ to create my map. I have not found any good tutorials or documentation on this yet.

Here is my issue:

I am attempting to load a very large world map into my game. Each gridspace is 32x32 pixels. The map itself is 1000x1000 gridspaces. At a first glimpse, this seems bad because of the size. When I loaded this WorldMap into my game XNA threw an out of memory error because the image was too large. I feel like I am approaching this from the wrong angle. Does anyone know a better way to handle a large world map? It would be nice to only load in what the character can see, that would be way more efficient however, that does not solve my problem of loading this huge image. Another idea would be a smaller image for each area but I am not sure how to do that since it's a world. Any ideas, tips, tutorials, I am sure this is a common issue that has been solved several times using several different solutions. Thank you!

Comment: Do you actually need to *load* this 1Gpx image? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Sorry I can't really help, but I'd be under the impression that the best solution would be to have single tile images which you can repeat. Then, build your game map in code (ie. a matrix type array in your actual game) or via an XML/Map Definition file. Then you can make an engine which will draw the individual tiles. Of course this is just theory and I haven't developed a game like this so wouldn't really know - Hence a comment ;-)

Comment: The entire world map will have a base layer of an ocean and on top it, I have added layers of dirt and grass islands. The water would need collision and I would need a third layer to mark collision on objects such as rocks.

Answer (score 2):

When I was creating 2d XNA game I did:

1. My own format of binary map file. This file contains map name, map width and height in tiles etc and map array. It was simply byte array (byte[]) where each value corresponds  to tile type.
2. Tile type. It's just simple class with some properties: movement cost (-1 if player can't move over this tile), which types of creatures can live in this tile, tile images etc.
3. Tile types db. It's just xml file contains tile types.

So, when game loads a level:

1. Load map and find in tile type db tiles which used in this map.
2. Load appropriate images for this tiles. Only once. It can be reused for different tiles with same type.
3. Draw only visible (for player) tiles with some reserve. As example draw only screen_width/tile_size_y*2 in width and screen_height/tile_size_y*2 in height. When player moves recalc visible tiles.